# Can an eigenvalue problem have eigenvalues outside of the diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In a dynamical meteorology class we came across a linear system of the kind $$ \begin{pmatrix}
-\lambda  & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & -\lambda  & -\lambda \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & -\lambda 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix} $$

in which we must determine the eigenvalues $\lambda$ in order to have non-zero solutions. My question is, how can this be an eigenvalue problem, given there is a $\lambda$ outside of the diagonal? As far as I know, and eigenvalue problem has the form
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
-\lambda  & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & -\lambda  & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & -\lambda 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix} $$ 
where 
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & 0 & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

and $$ X=\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}$$
so that $$(A-\lambda I)X=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix} \ \ \ $$

but in this case, instead of an identity matrix multiplied by $\lambda$ and subtracted from $A$, what I have is $$(A-\lambda B)X=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix} \ \ \ $$

where $$ B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

How can $\lambda$ be the eigenvalue in this case?

Comment: Likely it was just a typo.  Eigenvalue problems seek to solve $Ax=\lambda x$ for nonzero vectors $x$.

Comment: Actually those are called "generalized eigenvalue". But probably it was just a typo

Comment: thank you. It wasn't actually a typo, I remember someone asking the same question, but don't remember the explanation. But now that I know what it is called I can look it up